# How to use font awesome in an Ext.panel.Tool

Tags: extjs, font-awesome, extjs6

I need to customize an Ext.panel.Tool to display the icon 'fa fa-file-excel-o' from font awesome in the header of a grid. Following what I found online I have declared the tool:

```
    header: {
    itemPosition: 1, // after title before collapse tool
    items: [{
        xtype: 'tool',
        type: 'export',
        cls:'component-tool-export',
        handler: 'doExportData'
    }]
    },
```

And the css:

```
.component-tool-export .x-tool-export{
  background-image:none !important;
  content: "\f1c3" !important;
}
```

The tool is there and I can click on it, but the icon is not displayed. Can anyone give me some hint to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not adding content to the :before pseudo element, which is required to have the content displayed. You could use the following CSS:

```
.component-tool-export .x-tool-export{
  background-image:none !important;
  font: 16px/1 FontAwesome;
}
.component-tool-export .x-tool-export:before{
  content: "\f1c3" !important;
}
```

But if you already use Sencha CMD, I would recommend to conform with Sencha's own SASS files and make use of the full feature set of Sencha Fashion:

```
$tool-export-glyph: dynamic($fa-var-file-excel-o $tool-glyph-font-size $font-icon-font-family);

.#{$prefix}tool-export {
    @include font-icon($tool-export-glyph);
    background: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The first piece of code does not work, I had already tried with ':before'. The second part with SASS works like a charm. I guess I cant delay to learn SASS anymore.

Comment: @HernanDiaz I have looked it up and improved the first piece of code. It should be working as well now.

Comment: I could never get to this solution by myself. Too much insight needed. The second solution works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @AlfonsoNishikawa You can look into the sass files in the `/ext` directory, see how Sencha did it and copy it over.

Comment: @Alexander Everything is easy when you understand it ;)